# Turn my machine in a hotspot/proxy

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, proxy, hotspot

My workplace does not provide a wifi... only wired connection... but my machine has a working wifi card... is there a way to "bridge" my wired connection, making my iphone connect to it and use it as if the own machine is being used? (the idea is to make my machine provide a wifi-connection and route it through my wired connection)

Details:

- My machine OS is win 2012 server
- I have full admin rights to my machine
- There is a corporate-proxy

PS: If more details needed pls ask!

Comment: There may be very good reasons why your workplace does not provide Wi-Fi. Indeed, you may well find that trying to do so without explicit permission would be highly "career limiting" if not career terminating.

Comment: @JulianKnight "There may be very good reasons why your workplace does not provide Wi-Fi." yeah! cost-saving! trust me! and no, I evaluated the complete scene and i think it would be a career booster! sot of "hey that sys-arch there is a really smart guy! and why are we not providing wi-fi again???"

Answer (score -1):

Searching the web for "windows wifi hotspot" turns up a whole bunch of results. Also, http://download.cnet.com/windows/wireless-networking-software/ has several examples in the top 5.